# Test GPS route tracker without driving on road

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, google-maps

Using GMSMapView (google maps). I have created a route from current location to some selected locations (free car parking spaces). Now I need to test the route updating as when user drives on road. I myself, for testing is not supposed to drive. Is there any tool available for iOS (swift is preferred). I have heard in Android it is Moc Testing kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has built-in Location Simulation feature.

[image: Location button]

Read [this official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html) for usage.